# Tracking object using survey shot

Tags: tracking

I've downloaded some tutorial footage that includes a Survey shot, it is basically a person moving aroung a sword. I tracked the camera without a problem, but the object is having some problems. I am trying to use the survey shot but I have no idea how to do that in Blender. Does anybody knows how?

This is the link https://www.hollywoodcamerawork.com/tracking-plates.html
just scroll down and will see the Virtual sword.

[image: This is the main shot]

[This is the survey shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEYXO.jpg)

[image: This is the main shot]

Comment: I do not know what a "survey shot" is.

Comment: @David I just edited my question. It is related to survey tracking using what is called a survey shot.

Comment: @David What I did for that particular shot was to track the survey shot, just put on some markers and export them to 3ds max to create a mesh that will work as proxy mesh, then track the main shot, add the proxy and made constraints to the correspondent vertex.

In this video is explained that last process.

https://vimeo.com/14352900